# Magento and PayPal Payments Advanced User Authentication Issue

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, paypal, paypal-payments-advanced

I'm using PayPal Payments Advanced and I am receiving an error when clicking the button "Place Order" on my one page checkout. The error is "User Authentication Failed". I have confirmed my credentials in Magento for PayPal. I have gone over the steps provided by both PayPal and Magento for integration multiple times, but have been unable to proceed past this error.

I have tried various solutions for Google, such as updating the Cancel, Error and Return URLs on Manager.PayPal.com, but with no success.

Comment: i have same problem can any one help?

Comment: Is it solved or not? Tell me the solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue and is the default response for many of the various errors that can occur. If you're experiencing this in the Paypal Sandbox, it is generally suggested that you create a new WPP or other account type user for the gateway account.

If you're using a production account you should contact customer support. In many cases an API key can be invalidated by seemingly fraudulent activity. In other cases the generation of a new API key resolves issues.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced such kind of errors and issues during **PayPal Advanced Payment Gateway** with Magento 2. After, doing a lot of R&D on Google. I found out that you need to enter such Required Fields:

Login into manager.paypal.com to get all such credentials.

- Email Associated with PayPal: Merchant PayPal ID.
- Partner: PayPal/ VeriSign.
- Vendor: Payflow Pro login Name
- User: Payflow Pro login Name
- Password: Payflow pro password

That's it.
By entering all these credentials, you can access the PayPal Advanced on the website.

Thanks!

Siddhant Jain

Comment: I am still getting the same error. Any other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Paypal has regular paypal account which can be used for paypal express.

In order to use direct payment on the website, you need to have payflow account setup associated with this paypal account.

To access this payflow account features you need to login to manager.paypal.com account. This is separate login to regular paypal.com. It has separate user name and password.

In this manager account you need to set ID and password that is used Payflow Pro Login and Payflow Pro password.